# Ruby TCPServer to get client ip address

Tags: ruby

This is my not working script (just hangs...)

```
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.new 2000

loop do
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    sock_domain, remote_port, remote_hostname, remote_ip = server.peeraddr
    client.puts "Hello !"
    client.puts "Time is #{Time.now}"
    puts "connection coming from #{remote_ip} and port #{remote_port}"
    client.close
  end
end
```

I want to have an output of the connecting client IP but the connection is made and nothing happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code is fine, except this:

```
sock_domain, remote_port, remote_hostname, remote_ip = server.peeraddr
```

Should be this:

```
sock_domain, remote_port, remote_hostname, remote_ip = client.peeraddr
                                                       ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Where is the documentaton for client.peeraddr? I don't see it here:
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.9/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/SSL/SSLSocket.html

Comment: It's part of TCPSocket which is a class of IPSocket: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/IPSocket.html#method-i-peeraddr . SSLSocket is just an IO wrapper, you need to query the underlying socket, not the wrapper.